# Poshy Tip not moving along with scrolling element

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, tooltip

When creating a [Poshy Tip](http://vadikom.com/demos/poshytip/) inside a scrolling div, the tip does not move when the div is scrolled.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vc99y/2/).

I'm assuming this is because the tip div is a child of the `<body>` and not of the scrolling container div.

Is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[JSFIDDLE v2](http://jsfiddle.net/v3r6s/2/)**

**Description:**

The PoshyTip is actually getting created at the end of the document and given a position:absolute with a top:0px and a z-index:1000 which means it will always overlay the body and be positioned to it. In order for this to work you will have to alter the DOM to move the PoshyTip into the Click me so it will look like this:

```
<span id="tip">Click me
    <div class="tip-yellow" style="visibility: inherit; left: 62px; top: 0px; border: 0px; padding: 0px; background-image: none; background-color: transparent; opacity: 1;"><table class="tip-table" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 169px;"><tbody><tr><td class="tip-top tip-bg-image" colspan="2" style="background-image: url(http://vadikom.com/demos/poshytip/src/tip-yellow/tip-yellow.png);"><span></span></td><td class="tip-right tip-bg-image" rowspan="2" style="background-image: url(http://vadikom.com/demos/poshytip/src/tip-yellow/tip-yellow.png);"><span></span></td></tr><tr><td class="tip-left tip-bg-image" rowspan="2" style="background-image: url(http://vadikom.com/demos/poshytip/src/tip-yellow/tip-yellow.png);"><span></span></td><td style="width: 100%;"><div class="tip-inner tip-bg-image" style="background-image: url(http://vadikom.com/demos/poshytip/src/tip-yellow/tip-yellow.png);">Scroll and I won't move</div></td></tr><tr><td class="tip-bottom tip-bg-image" colspan="2" style="background-image: url(http://vadikom.com/demos/poshytip/src/tip-yellow/tip-yellow.png);"><span></span></td></tr></tbody></table><div class="tip-arrow tip-arrow-left" style="visibility: inherit;"></div></div>
</span>
```

Next you will need to set the SPANs position:relative so it will be like this:

```
<span id="tip" style="position:relative;">Click me
```

Finally you need to set top:-8px for the tip-yellow class

```
<div class="tip-yellow" style="top:-8px; visibility: inherit; left: 62px; top: 0px; border: 0px; padding: 0px; background-image: none; background-color: transparent; opacity: 1;">
```

Comment: Yes, then it works, because then the body is scrolling and not the container: since the tip is inside the body, it scrolls along. But I'm wondering if there is a way to have the tip scroll along with the container instead of the body.

Comment: Thanks MonkeyZeus! This was exactly the answer I was hoping for. Much appreciated.

Comment: Glad I could help! I do want to mention on thing though. If you have multiple PoshyTips on a page and call the .append($('.tip-yellow')) then you may get some undesired results because it seems like all of the tips get the class name of "tip-yellow"

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I ran into. I created another question for that. Feel free to shine your light on that one as well :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18064316/setting-id-and-adding-css-class-to-poshy-tip-tooltip-div

Comment: Cool, i'll check it out

Answer (score 0):

i'm not fomelar with this plug-in but after i look around it on the web i come to an answer about your question

you can look on the style attribute of the tool tip warp and see that its include a "left" and "right" property. there is no position css property, there for its get the default value "static".

you can read more about the "position" property in general and "static" value particularly on  [w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-position). in general line i can tall you that as long as the "position" property is not "fixed" the element would not be fixed to the first "position : relative" div

Comment: Are you talking about the div with class tip-yellow? That one does have its position set to absolute. Perhaps you could update the fiddle with your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Since the poshytip is overlay the body and be positioned to it, why couldn't changing the source file jquery.poshytip.js, replacing ".appendTo(document.body)" with ".insertAfter(this.$elm)". Then the tip can scroll along with the scrolling element.