# Setting id and adding CSS class to Poshy Tip tooltip div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tooltip

How do I set the id or add an extra CSS class to a tooltip div created with Poshy Tip? I'd like to be able to distinguish between different tooltips that are displayed at the same time.

I've tried adding the extra CSS class in the initialization of the tooltip, but this breaks the layout as there is some CSS generated on the fly by Poshy Tip that stops functioning correctly. The plugin provides no option to set the id:

```js
$('#tip').poshytip({
    className: 'tip-yellow',
    // Replacing the previous line with the next one breaks the layout:
    // className: 'tip-yellow extraClass',
    // This option doesn't exist:
    // id: 'myId',
    ...
}
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Etvku/).

Can we add extraClass and set myId after initialization?

My jQuery skills are limited, so chances are I'm simply overlooking something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get the text-decoration to work but I did change the color:

I commented out classname: 'tip-yellow'

and added this at the bottom:

```
$('.tip-yellow:last').addClass('extraClass');
```

[Your Fiddle v2](http://jsfiddle.net/Etvku/2/)

UPDATE: add ID to it as well

[Your Fiddle v3](http://jsfiddle.net/Etvku/3/)

Comment: Thanks MonkeyZeus. I'll accept this as the answer, even though it is, of course, a hack. :-) There seems to be no better way, though.

Comment: Haha yea, I won't deny that I hacked it. I've looked into it but never worked with PoshyTips. However I did find qTip2 @ http://qtip2.com/ and I definitely recommend it especially if you are looking to customize the tooltip extensively. Be careful of google searches when looking for help though because there seems to be A LOT of v1 answers/solutions instead of v2

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'll go check it out.

Comment: No problem, I just tried it with the Overflow issue from your first question and I think you will find the same issue because it positions itself in the same absolute and z-index manner. But at least the styling is highly customizable :)

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate your help :-)